# Html email header not positioning as should

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I was asked to code an html mail (for mailing campaigns).
I've got everything working except the following piece of code.
What I try to do is having an image with other elements on top like titles, a button, a logo, ...
I had all that (not commented lines), but to make it responsive I had to make some changes (commented lines) and then the layout was completely messed up.
To make it even more of a challenge, it's quite horrifying to watch in outlook (even the not commented lines) so a solution for that would be nice to have as well (outlook seems to strip all positioning attributes)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
    <style>
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700);
        html {
            font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif; 
            font-size: 13px; 
            line-height: 20px; 
            /*color: #87888a; */
            color: #00000;
            letter-spacing: 0,5px;
        }
        #headertable {
            border-bottom: 5px solid #E40520; 
            position: relative;
            max-width: 600px;
        }
        .absolutepos {
            position: absolute; 
            left: 0; 
            right: 0; 
            bottom: 0;
        }
        #invitation {
            color: #ffffff; 
            text-transform: uppercase; 
            padding:5px 23px 5px 15px; 
            font-size: 24px; 
            border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;  
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; 
            -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; 
            background-color: #E40520; 
            border: solid #E40520; 
            display: inline-block; 
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 30px; 
            line-height: 24px; 
            color: #ffffff; 
            font-weight: normal; 
            text-transform: uppercase; 
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 20px; 
            line-height: 24px; 
            color: #ffffff; 
            font-weight: normal; 
            text-transform: uppercase; 
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            margin: 20px 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .submit-button {
            padding:7px 12px; 
            text-decoration: none; 
            border-radius:5px; 
            -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
            -moz-border-radius:5px; 
            background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
            /*border:solid #87888A;*/ 
            display:inline-block; 
            font-size: 18px; 
            line-height: 24px; 
            color: #ffffff;
            text-transform: uppercase; 
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            transition: background .2s ease-in-out, color .2s ease-in-out;
        }
        .submit-button:hover {
            background: #E40520;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#eeeeee">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="600" height="290" id="headertable">
<!--<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" id="headertable" bgcolor="#00000">-->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="absolutepos" width="600" height="290" style="z-index: -1; top: 0;" alt="header_image" src="https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg" >
                <!--<img class="absolutepos" style="max-width: 600px; z-index: -1; top: 0;" alt="header_image" src="https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg" >-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="absolutepos" style="top: 15px; padding: 0 0 0 20px;">
                <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" title="google">
                    <img width="175" height="47" alt="logo" src="https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/Olympic-logo.png">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="absolutepos" style="top: 80px;">
                <span id="invitation">type</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="absolutepos" style="top: 150px;">
                <h1>Big title</h1>
                <h2>subtitle</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="absolutepos" style="top: 225px;">
                <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" title="Register" class="submit-button">
                    Register
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="padding: 40px 30px 10px 30px;">
                ...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` won't work in gmail.
Outlook is using HTML renderer, so you might run into some issues in Outlook as well.

[Source: Detailed list for CSS support in different email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/b/)

Comment: I know. As I stated above outlook doesn't represent it as should (the image is displayed above the text). But since I'm a DBA and no specialist I don't know how to solve all this

Comment: You can follow the link I provided and you will be able to see all supported CSS rules in mail clients. Unfortunately using `position:absolute` or negative margins is not supported. 

To answer your question, you shouldn't try to put text elements on top of the image because it is not supported in all email clients, especially gmail and outlook.

Comment: So you're saying I need to use an all-including image (so no text or buttons on the image)?

Comment: One alternative option would be to add the text in the image itself (not with CSS, but in photo editor), and then use the image. Buttons should go outside of the image.